# bs4 extracting data from specific tables and columns

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull data from specific columns in the 4th and 5th table from this website https://hollowknight.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_Values_and_Enemy_Health_(Hollow_Knight)

Here's my code

```
import bs4
import requests

url = "https://hollowknight.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_Values_and_Enemy_Health_(Hollow_Knight)"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
names = []
number = []
for row in rows[1:]:
   names.append(row.find_all('td')[0])
   number.append(row.find_all('td')[1])
   
for first, second in zip(names, number):
    print(first.text, second.text)
```

For some reason it can't see the 4th or 5th table. However, if I replace the 3 in

```
table = soup.find_all('table')[3]
```

with a 2 or lower it sees it just fine. Can anyone help me understand why it can't see the last 2 tables in the website?

Comment: What columns specifically do you want?

Comment: i think it is working `soup.find_all("table)[4]` and please share what table you want to find from URL

Comment: The tables I want are "Standard Enemies" and "Bosses and Minibosses" and the columns are the Haelth columns

Comment: @MendelG Sorry I'm new to this, your solution worked the best. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get *specific* columns, you can use the [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS selector.

In order to use a CSS selector, use the [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `.find_all()`.

This will find the tables "Standard Enemies" and "Bosses and Minibosses"  while *only selecting* the "health" column:

```
standard_enemy_health = soup.select(
    "table:nth-of-type(4) tr:nth-of-type(n+3) td:nth-of-type(6)"
)

bosses_health = soup.select("table:nth-of-type(5) tr:nth-of-type(n+3) td:nth-of-type(4)")
```

Answer (score 0):

First `df` return as Standard Enemies and `df1` return as Bosses and Minibosses for that you can use directly `pd.read_html` as pass data it will return as DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

main_data=soup.find_all("table")[3]
df=pd.read_html(str(main_data))[0]


main_data=soup.find_all("table")[4]
df1=pd.read_html(str(main_data))[0]
```